# How to save and use cookiea with Restkit -objective-c

Tags: objective-c, session, cookies, restkit

I'm using a Rails server and I have an application with Restkit to access the server.

My server uses session cookie to login. When I post in /sessions with my account info, I logged in and I can access privates area from server.
Question is, I don't want to login whenever I want to use the application. I don't know how restkit works with cookies, but when my session is "open", I don't need to worry about it. But now I want to access private areas, using my cookie.

When I login:

```
'POST /sessions HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:3000
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Content-Type: application/json
 Content-Length: 74
 Accept-Language: en-us
 Accept: application/json
 Connection: keep-alive
 User-Agent: TicketIn/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/11.4.2

 {"session":{"email":"***","password":"***"}}'
```

---

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
 Etag: "7215ee9c7d9dc229d2921a40e899ec5f"
 Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
 X-Request-Id: 41f0c482720d6cdcedb64071a6ebf9e7
 X-Runtime: 0.222790
 Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-04-20)
 Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 13:23:28 GMT
 Content-Length: 1
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Set-Cookie: _vitrine_session=*session*; path=/; HttpOnly
```

And when I try to access private area:

```
 GET /ingressos HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:3000
 If-None-Match: "310fd8ebf912d0633caa05a91ce56fcc"
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept: application/json
 Cookie:      
 _vitrine_session=*session*
 Content-Length: 0
 Accept-Language: en-us
 Connection: keep-alive
 User-Agent: TicketIn/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/11.4.2
```

But when I try to access private area whithout login first:

```
 GET /ingressos HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:3000
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept: application/json
 Content-Length: 0
 Connection: keep-alive
 Accept-Language: en-us
 User-Agent: TicketIn/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/11.4.2
```

So How can I include the cookie in my http requests??

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a cookie that you want to add so that it is sent by RestKit? Or you want that RestKit should use an existing cookie following your login (which should be automatic)?

Comment: So, when I login, I wanna storage this cookie to use later. For example, to not do the login with the server again, just use my session cookie to access the private area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestKit is built on top of standard URL loading system. As such, you have complete control over what cookies are used by setting the content of `NSHTTPCookieStorage` (and if you want dig, changing `setHTTPShouldHandleCookies` property on `NSMutableURLRequest`).

So, you can add and remove cookies from `NSHTTPCookieStorage` as and when you require.

Comment: Well, I tried this but, even with the cookie saved, when I'm performing a http request (GET, for an example), in a private area, using tcpmonitor, my header doesnt have the cookie that I have set up.

Comment: And the domain was an exact match?

Comment: Well, thats a good point. I think I don't configured all correctly, because I don't know how to set all informations for the cookie field. You see?

Comment: You may want to create a new question to ask about your cookie settings. It's all about `initWithProperties:` probably...

Comment: Ok, I'll analise my code and do another question as you suggest. Just one thing.... My domain should match with the host? Or the entire path of the request? Thanks, I'll accept your answer!